# All possible containers for a Real Time Messaging Protocol stream

Tags: audio, video, containers, rtmp, codec

I am involved in building a Real Time Messaging Protocol Parser.I am collecting the video/audio data from the RTMP packets.Now to play a video in any player I need to know the container format as well as the codec used.In the video data I am getting from the RTMP packets I know the codec used (for eg. On2 VP6).But I don't know how to know the container of the audio/video stream that I am receiving . So should I assume that RTMP support only FLV container ??? Or is it possible for me to get audio/video packets from any other container formats ?? If Yes then how to know the type of container used from the RTMP data from the information present in RTMP packet ?Adobe specification for RTMP does not provide any information regarding the container of the audio/video data. Any help on this ??? I am stuck here for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit wrong question.

RTMP is a transport protocol that includes containers inside.

Technically it is not correct to say that RTMP carries FLV, because FLV has two layers of incapsulation and RTMP carries only bottom level.

So, it is right to say that RTMP can transfer only those codecs that FLV can and it is not 100% right to say that RTMP transfers FLV.

Adobe's specification of RTMP was created not for developers but for a legal issue against Wowza, so it is not written for you to understand what is happening. Read sources of red5, crtmp or some other rtmp server, they are rather easy to understand.