# python ffmpeg streaming to rtmp server "Unable to find a suitable output format"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to write a code to send the face redacted video to a rtmp stream. I am stuck at this error

```
[NULL @ 000002b631764dc0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://f7a22cf83cc841ceaf6f.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/ffd956a1'
```

rtmp://f7a22cf83cc841ceaf6f.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/5ffd956a1: Invalid argument

```
import cv2
import subprocess

rtmp_url = "rtmp://f7a22cf83cc841ceaf6f.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/5ffd956a1"

video_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(video_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(video_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(video_cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
print(width)
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-loglevel', 'error',
           '-y',
           # Input
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', str(width) + 'x' + str(height),
           '-r', str(fps),
           # Output
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',                    
           '-vcodec', 'h264',                   
           rtmp_url
           ]


print(command)
# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:        
    ret, image_frame = video_cam.read()
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Resources/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_frame,1.3,5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image_frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255.0,0),3)
        face_color = image_frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(face_color, (51, 51), 0)
        image_frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] = blur
    cv2.imshow('Face Detected',image_frame)
    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(image_frame.tobytes())
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the output of my ffmpeg command, if i print the command variable

```
['ffmpeg', '-loglevel', 'error', '-y', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', '-s', '640x480', '-r', '30', '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'ultrafast', '-vcodec', 'h264', 'rtmp://f7a22cf83cc841ceaf6fd7d2bd7fb019.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/c9c612df89ca4722b942c425ffd956a1']
```

Comment: The error message says it all, your FFmpeg command is missing output `-f` option. According [to this](https://ottverse.com/rtmp-streaming-using-ffmpeg-tutorial/), you need to use `-f flv`. [This related past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785114/all-possible-containers-for-a-real-time-messaging-protocol-stream) might be useful for you, too.

Comment: thanks so much @kesh and it does help i see but now i get an error - Option video_size not found.   I guess its because -s is deprecated but even if i make it video_size the error remains. 
this is my ffmpeg command now

 ffmpeg -loglevel error -y -f flv -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -video_size 640x480 -r 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -vcodec h264 rtmp://fd7d2bd7fb019.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/c9c612df89ca4722b

Comment: AFAIK `-s` is not deprecated in FFmpeg so donno why it's not working. But I noticed that you have both `c:v` and `vcodec` defined, which are the same option. What happens if you drop `-vcodec` and define `-s 640x480` in your output option

Comment: actually the error was something more silly than I could've expected. the rtmp endpoint is supposed to have endpoint name appended to it, it started working when i added the rtmp endpoint. Thanks for your help, options that worked
['ffmpeg','-y', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height), '-r', str(fps), '-i', '-', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
'-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url
           ]

Comment: Glad you got it working!